# Need program to monitor Laptop CPU and GPU temperatures - with SHUTDOWN support

Tags: cpu, display, temperature

I just received my HP TX2500 tablet back from laptop service (fried ATI GPU) and I need software to monitor temperatures which supports emergency system shutdown after it surpasses a specified limit.

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 3):

[Real Temp](http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/) will work for this purpose. It has an option to add an EXE to be run as an alarm at specific (user set) temperature (for CPU or GPU). You can just add the shutdown.exe executable in C:\Windows\System32. Here's a screen shot, look where it says "Alarm EXE":

[image]

Comment: I would recommend the command line arguments `shutdown.exe /t 30` so it gives you a 30 second warning before it shuts down.

Comment: HI! real temp does not support my tx2650 processor (AMD TURION)

Comment: While realtemp is a nice and easy (just unzip) program, it does *not* show GPU temps on my Latitude e6540. I used Open Hardware Monitor instead, which is just as easy (plus open source) and does show GPU temp and fan speed: http://openhardwaremonitor.org

Answer (score 0):

CoreTemp was program that i needed. I reccoment it to use on any pc/laptop. It does support AMD and Intel proccessors.